# what is a 'layer' in a neural network

Tags: neural-network

Below I've drawn a typical feed forward neural network:

[image: Typical Feed Forward Neural Network]

Now my question is, as far as lingo goes, what is a layer?

Could each individual process (rectangle) be considered a layer? or is a layer the combination a single row of the flow diagram? I sometimes see the Multiply + Add as a single layer, and the nonlinear function (relu) as a separate layer. But I would really appreciate a definitive answer.

I often find on online videos teaching people about Neural Networks, the instructors themselves mix up the number of layers within a single example.

Comment: That's a really confusing way to look at a neural network. Try the diagram to the right on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Background

Comment: I personally base it off the [activations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function). One activation = one layer.

Comment: this is by no means a formal definition, but intuitively - "a set of nodes that have the same distance from the inputs"

Comment: @yurib I think that is, not just informal, but also a wrong definition. You may not want to consider two independent layers as one thing just because they have the same distance to the input.

Comment: I think the confusion may stem from the fact that "layer" is used to mean a set of nodes in one context (like the ones provided in this post) and an atomic operation on the set of nodes in another context (like all major neural network libraries where a layer corresponds to an atomic operation such as a linear transformation or an activation function). One layer in the former context typically corresponds two layers in the latter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With your diagram, each row is essentially a layer.  But as @beaker states it is not the best way to visualize a neural network.

Taking an image from [here](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/) will help make this clear.

[image]

Layer is a general term that applies to a collection of 'nodes' operating together at a specific depth within a neural network.

The **input layer** is contains your raw data (you can think of each variable as a 'node').

The **hidden layer(s)** are where the *black magic* happens in neural networks.  Each layer is trying to *learn* different aspects about the data by minimizing an error/cost function.  The most intuitive way to understand these layers is in the context of 'image recognition' such as a face.  The first layer may learn edge detection, the second may detect eyes, third a nose, etc.  This is not exactly what is happening but the idea is to break the problem up in to components that different levels of abstraction can piece together much like our own brains work (hence the name 'neural networks').

The **output layer** is the simplest, usually consisting of a single output for classification problems.  Although it is a single 'node' it is still considered a *layer* in a neural network as it could contain multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The core building block of neural networks is the layer, a data-processing module that
you can think of as a filter for data. Some data goes in, and it comes out in a more useful
form. Specifically, layers extract representations out of the data fed into them—hopefully,
representations that are more meaningful for the problem at hand. Most of
deep learning consists of chaining together simple layers that will implement a form
of progressive data distillation. A deep-learning model is like a sieve for data processing,
made of a succession of increasingly refined data filters—the layers.

Answer (score 1):

Goodfellow, 2016 in his book ["Deep Learning"](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html), defines a network as a function composition, where each function is a layer:

[image: f^{(3)}(f^{(2)}(f^{(1)}(x)))]

However, from the original question I would not consider things that can be vectorized (multiply and adding bias) as separate layers, though ReLU or other activation functions are most often seen as layers, which also fits the definition given by Goodfellow.